# ¿Cómo solucionar el error HttpError 404.15 - Not Found en un proyecto MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy implementando un Login en mi proyecto MVC 5, así que añadí un filtro en el Filter.config para asegurarme de que sólo los usuarios con autentificación puedan interactuar con los distintos modulos. Sin embargo, al correr el proyecto me sale el siguiente error:

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
>   El módulo Solicitar filtrado está configurado para denegar una solicitud cuando la cadena de consulta sea demasiado larga.

El código en el Filter.config:

```
   public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```

El código del controlador del login:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(ClsLogin User)
    {
        UserBusinessLogic UserBL = new UserBusinessLogic();
        string message = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (UserBL.CheckUserLogin(User) > 0)
            {
                message = "Success";
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(User.NumeroEmpleado.ToString(), false);
                Session["UserLog"] = User.NumeroEmpleado.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Uno de los campos es incorrecto";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            message = "Todos los campos son requeridos";
        }

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Account", "Login");
        }
    }
```

Intente con esto para darle solución pero no ha resultado:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <remove segment="bin"/>
    </hiddenSegments>
    <requestLimits maxUrl="4096" maxQueryString="10240"></requestLimits>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Cuando quito el filtro todo vuelve a funcionar. Esta es la primera vez que hago algo así por lo que no sé demasiado al respecto ¿Alguna idea?

**EDITO**

Esta es mi vista:

```html
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Inicio de sesión</title>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/ionicons/ionicons-2.0.1/css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2 id="inicio-sesion"><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span>  Inicio de sesión</h2>
                    <div id="messenger"></div>
                </div>

                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="labels"><span class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:15px"></span>  Sucursal:</label>

                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownList("IdSucursal", new SelectList(ViewBag.sucursales, "IdSucursal", "NombreSucursal"), "SELECCIONE UNA SUCURSAL", new { Id = "Sucursal", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="labels"><span class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:15px"></span>  Número de empleado:</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NumeroEmpleado, new { Id = "NumeroEmpleado", @class = "form-control", pattern = "[0-9 ]+", title = "Introduzca sólo números", type = "text" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="labels"><span class="fa fa-unlock-alt" style="font-size:15px"></span>  Contraseña:</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Contrasena, new { Id = "Contrasena", type = "password", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <br />
                <a href="#" class="btn" id="Login"><span class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="font-size:15px" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Iniciar sesion</a>


                <div class="modal-footer"></div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myModal").modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
    });

    $("#Login").click(function () {
        var dataObject = { "NumeroEmpleado": $("#NumeroEmpleado").val(), "Contrasena": $("#Contrasena").val(), "NombreSucursal": $('#Sucursal :selected').text() };
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")',
            type: "POST",
            data: dataObject,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.toString() == "Success") {
                    //$("#myModal").modal('hide');
                    var url = '/Cartera/Aval';
                    location.href = url;
                }
                else {
                    $("#Sucursal").val("");
                    $("#NumeroEmpleado").val("");
                    $("#Contrasena").val("");
                    $("#NumeroEmpleado").focus();
                    $("#messenger").html('<div class ="failed">' + result + '</div>');
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                $("#Sucursal").val("");
                $("#NumeroEmpleado").val("");
                $("#Contrasena").val("");
                $("#NumeroEmpleado").focus();
                $("#messenger").html('<div class ="failed"> ¡Error! Intentelo de nuevo</div>');
            }
        });
    })
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Intente poner esto en mi Web.config, en lugar de usar el filtro:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users ="?" />
  <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

Tampoco surtió efecto.

Comment: hola Akiva, podrías colocar la vista de tu login por favor?

Comment: listo, añadí la vista :)

Comment: puedes determinar cual de los filtros esta fallando? es el de autorizacion o el HandleErrorAttribute. podrias definir uno u otro para determinarlo

Comment: ademas recuerda que el $("#Login").click(.. deberia estar definido dentro del $(document).ready(..

Comment: esta fallando en el filtro de autorización, ya corregí eso del $("#Login").click también, pondré como quedo en el post de la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

intenta colocar comillas en el `dataObject`:

```
var dataObject = { 
 "NumeroEmpleado": $("#NumeroEmpleado").val(),
 "Contrasena": $("#Contrasena").val(),
 "NombreSucursal": $('#Sucursal :selected').text() 
};
```

En el `JavaScript` es importante tener en cuenta la diferencia entre == e === mira: http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

**Actualización**

En las propiedades del proyecto web, es probable que lo tengas así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ser ese el caso, cambia `Windows Authentication` a `Disabled` y `Anonymous Authentication` a `Enabled`.

Comment: Lo hice así y ahora tengo este error: `La longitud de la cadena de consulta de esta solicitud supera el valor de maxQueryStringLength configurado.` He cambiado los valores del maxQueryStringLength pero sigue ocurriendo

Comment: respuesta actualizada

Comment: Ahora sucede algo extraño, con el `filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());` sigue mostrando el error del comentario anterior, pero si lo quito y en su lugar utilizo el `<authorization>` del Web.config me muestra el login normalmente, sin embargo al ingresar los datos y darle click al boton de iniciar sesion no ocurre nada

Comment: de hecho el color del fondo se oscurece más cada vez que le doy click al botón, como si se encimara un modal sobre otro, no se si me explico

Comment: lograste solucionarlo?