# como solucionar Error HTTP 404.15

Tags: ajax, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Mi problema es que al realizar una solicitud Ajax, al momento de enviar mi información recibo este error:

> El módulo Filtrado de solicitudes está configurado para denegar una solicitud cuando la cadena de consulta sea demasiado larga.

veo en otros foros que es por la cantidad enorme de información que envió a través de una solicitud GET. ¿Alguien sabe la solución a este Problema?

aqui dejo un ejemplo del Ajax y Metodo que uso

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("nuevaTarjetaCapacitacion", "TarjetaCapacitacion")",
            scriptCharset: "iso-8859-1",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=iso-8859-1",
            data: {
                TarjetaCapacitacionId: $("#TarjetaCapacitacionId").val(),
                NombreCurso: $("#NombreCurso").val(),
                Descripcion: $("#Descripcion").val(),
                FechaInicio: $("#FechaInicio").val(),
                FechaFin: $("#FechaFin").val(),
                //TipoCurso: $("#TipoCurso").val(),
                Departamentos: tarjetaCapacitacion.Departamentos.toString(),
                Puestos: tarjetaCapacitacion.Puestos.toString(),
                Personal: tarjetaCapacitacion.Personal.toString(),
                Instructores: tarjetaCapacitacion.Instructores.toString(),
                InstructoresExternos: JSON.stringify(tarjetaCapacitacion.InstructoresExternos),
                Documentos: tarjetaCapacitacion.Documentos.toString(),
                AprobacionId: $("#AprobacionId").val()
            }

 public JsonObject nuevaTarjetaCapacitacion(string NombreCurso, string Descripcion, string FechaInicio, string FechaFin, /*string TipoCurso,*/ string Departamentos, string Puestos, string Personal, string Instructores, string InstructoresExternos, string Documentos, int? AprobacionId)
        {
}
```

Comment: docs de microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/942071

Comment: hace tiempo respondí algo muy similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18082/822